# Trying to customise Roots Nav Walker Menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've got an HTML theme that I'm trying to convert Wordpress using the Roots frameword. The HTML theme requires that the menu structure `li` is like this:

```
<li><a href="#"><span>Item</span></a></li>
```

Whereas the default for the Roots nav output is like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
```

How can I add the spans into the menu?

Comment: Have you tried to add the span? Where have you added your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use wp_nav_menu.

arguments 'link_before' and 'link_after'

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => '',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '<span>',
    'link_after'      => '</span>',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

For reference : 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu